# Remove the table from a form in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Actually, I have created this table:

```
<table border='0' name="codes">

 <tr>

 <td><b> <?php echo xlt('Code'); ?> </b></td>

 <td><b> <?php echo xlt('Description'); ?> </b> </td>

 </tr>
 <? php ...... ?>

</table>
```

Due to the fact that the size of the table is dynamic ,I have a counter ($counter) that counts the rows of the table including the first row that shows the columns of the table (Code Description).
I also have created a button "Erase" and when I press it I want it to delete the table.

Below there is the code of the button "Erase":

```
<input type='button' value='<? php echo xla('Erase'); ?>' onclick="selcode(**' <? php echo $counter; ?>'**)" />
```

The button "Erase" calls the function selcode and inside this function there will be the code that delete the table. The function selcode is written in Javascript.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function selcode(counter) {. . . }

</script>
```

Can you help me please how can I delete the table? Also, the way I enter the php variable counter as function parameter is the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the erase button to type="reset" this will wipe out your form and clean it.

```
<input type='reset' value='< ? php echo xla('Erase'); ?>'>
```

I think thats what you are wanting?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function selcode() { 
   var el = document.getElementsByName("codes")[0];
   el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
   return false;
}
```